# ¿Cómo evitar múltiples señales itemChanged al cambiar un Item de un modelo en Qt?

Tags: qt, listview, checkbox, model-view-controller, sourcetree

Tengo un modelo `QStandardItemModel`en donde creo una jerarquía de árbol. A cada `item`de mi árbol le he dicho que sea `Checkable`. Y me he construido una función a la que llamo cada vez que cambia un `item`.

Dentro de esta función le digo que si he hecho `check`en un padre todos sus hijos también se hagan `check`y a su vez tengo implementado que si el `item` que se ha modificado es un hijo que compruebe el estado de todos los hijos de su padre, y si no están todos los hijos en `check`(o `uncheck`) que el padre se ponga en `PartiallyCheck`.

Yo quiero que a esta función se le llame solo cada vez que hago `check`o `uncheck`en uno de los `items`. Para ello he encontrado la señal `itemChanged`. El problema es que esta señal se llama cada vez que un item sE modifica, y no solo cuando es modificado por el usuario. Por lo tanto, en cuanto entro en la función para cambiar un padre pasa esto:

- Yo he cambiado padre a `Check`.
- Salta la señal `itemChanged`
- La función se llama y cambia hijo 1 a `Check`.
- Salta la señal `itemChanged`.
- La función detecta que un hijo se ha modificado y entonces comprueba todos los hijos. Ve que solo hay un cambiado. Pone al padre en `PartiallyCheck`.

Cuando lo que yo quiero es:

- Yo he cambiado padre a `Check`.
- Salta la señal `itemChanged`
- La función se llama y cambia hijo 1 a `Check`, cambia hijo 2 a `Check`... y así hasta completar todos los hijos.

Aquí dejo  la función y como emito la señal.

FUNCIÓN:

```
void CWindow::myIndexIsUpdate(QStandardItem *item)
{
    qDebug()<<"inside"<<myCounter;
    myCounter++;

    QModelIndex myItemIndex=item->index();
    if(!myItemIndex.isValid()){
        qDebug()<<"Item"<<item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)<<"index is not valid";
    }

    if(item->parent()==nullptr){
        qDebug()<<"Item"<<item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)<<"IS Parent";
        int MyChildrenCount=item->rowCount();
        for(int myChild=0;myChild<MyChildrenCount;myChild++){
            if(item->checkState()==Qt::Checked){
                item->child(myChild,0)->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
            }
            else if(item->checkState()==Qt::Unchecked){
                item->child(myChild,0)->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
            }

        }
    }
    else if(item->parent()->parent()==nullptr){

        qDebug()<<"Item"<<item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)<<"Parent a medias";
        int MyChildrenCount=item->rowCount();
        for(int myChild=0;myChild<MyChildrenCount;myChild++){
            if(item->checkState()==Qt::Checked){
                item->child(myChild,0)->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
            }
            else if(item->checkState()==Qt::Unchecked){
                item->child(myChild,0)->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
            }
            else{

            }
        }

    }
    else{
        int MyParentsChildren=item->parent()->rowCount();
        QStandardItem *parentItem=new QStandardItem;
        parentItem=item->parent();
        bool allChecked=true;
        bool allUnchecked=true;
        for(int myChild=0;myChild<MyParentsChildren;myChild++){
            qDebug()<<"Item is..."<<myChild<<parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState();
            if (parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState()!=Qt::Checked){

                allChecked=false;
            }
            else if(parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState()!=Qt::Unchecked){
                allUnchecked=false;
            }
        }
        if (allChecked==true){
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        }
        else if(allUnchecked==true){
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        }
        else{
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::PartiallyChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

CONEXIÓN DE LA SEÑAL Y LA FUNCIÓN:

```
connect(p_treeModel,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem *)),this,
                           SLOT(myIndexIsUpdate(QStandardItem *)));
```

IMAGEN DE MI ESTRUCTURA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

He conseguido solucionar el problema poniendo `blockSignals`para bloquear las señales del modelo dentro de la función. Bloqueo las señales justo al entrar en la función y las desbloqueo justo al salir.

Aquí dejo la función para que se vea. También he modificado algo otros aspectos de la función para poder tener todas las funcionalidades deseadas.

```
void CWindow::myIndexIsUpdate(QStandardItem *item)
{
    p_treeModel->blockSignals(true);
    qDebug()<<"inside"<<myCounter;
    myCounter++;
    QModelIndex myItemIndex=item->index();
    if(!myItemIndex.isValid()){
        qDebug()<<"Item"<<item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)<<"index is not valid";
        return;
    }
    if(item->parent()==nullptr){
        qDebug()<<"Item"<<item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)<<"IS Parent";
        int MyChildrenCount=item->rowCount();
        int myChild=0;
        while(myChild<MyChildrenCount){
            //  p_treeModel->blockSignals(true);
            QStandardItem *itemChild=new QStandardItem;
            itemChild=item->child(myChild,0);
            if(item->checkState()==Qt::Checked){
                itemChild->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
                int MyChildrenCountChild=itemChild->rowCount();
                int myChildChild=0;
                while(myChildChild<MyChildrenCountChild){
                    //  p_treeModel->blockSignals(true);
                    itemChild->child(myChildChild,0)->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
                    myChildChild++;
                }
                //  p_treeModel->blockSignals(false);
            }
            else if(item->checkState()==Qt::Unchecked){
                itemChild->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
                int MyChildrenCountChild=itemChild->rowCount();
                int myChildChild=0;
                while(myChildChild<MyChildrenCountChild){
                    // p_treeModel->blockSignals(true);
                    itemChild->child(myChildChild,0)->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
                    myChildChild++;
                }
                //p_treeModel->blockSignals(false);
            }
            else{

            }
            myChild++;
        }
        // p_treeModel->blockSignals(false);
    }
    else if(item->parent()->parent()==nullptr){
        qDebug()<<"Item"<<item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)<<"Parent a medias";
        int MyChildrenCount=item->rowCount();
        int myChild=0;
        while(myChild<MyChildrenCount){
            p_treeModel->blockSignals(true);
            if(item->checkState()==Qt::Checked){
                item->child(myChild,0)->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
            }
            else if(item->checkState()==Qt::Unchecked){
                item->child(myChild,0)->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
            }
            else{

            }
            myChild++;
        }
       // p_treeModel->blockSignals(false);

        int MyParentsChildren=item->parent()->rowCount();
        QStandardItem *parentItem=new QStandardItem;
        parentItem=item->parent();
        bool allChecked=true;
        bool allUnchecked=true;
        for(int myChild=0;myChild<MyParentsChildren;myChild++){
            qDebug()<<"Item is..."<<myChild<<parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState();
            if (parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState()!=Qt::Checked){
                allChecked=false;
            }
            else if(parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState()!=Qt::Unchecked){
                allUnchecked=false;
            }
        }
        if (allChecked==true){
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        }
        else if(allUnchecked==true){
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        }
        else{
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::PartiallyChecked);
        }
    }
    else{
        int MyParentsChildren=item->parent()->rowCount();
        QStandardItem *parentItem=new QStandardItem;
        parentItem=item->parent();
        bool allChecked=true;
        bool allUnchecked=true;
        for(int myChild=0;myChild<MyParentsChildren;myChild++){
            qDebug()<<"Item is..."<<myChild<<parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState();
            if (parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState()!=Qt::Checked){

                allChecked=false;
            }
            else if(parentItem->child(myChild,0)->checkState()!=Qt::Unchecked){
                allUnchecked=false;
            }
        }
        if (allChecked==true){
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        }
        else if(allUnchecked==true){
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        }
        else{
            parentItem->setCheckState(Qt::PartiallyChecked);
        }
    }
    p_treeModel->blockSignals(false);
}
```

Y aquí la imagen reprensentativa de la solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]